# Android highcharts library chart loading completed listener event

Tags: android, highcharts, linechart

I am new to Highcharts. I want to know when the data loading gets completed on android highcharts chart. Is there some listener available for the same? On search I could find only highcharts web related solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `HIEvents` object to the chart. In this object you can define a few features, like the `load` callback.

Comment: How can I attach HIEvents to chart? I couldn't find any method with parameter as HIEvents in options and chart setters. It will be helpful if you could provide the code for the same

Comment: @PoojaRajendranC here you can find the HIEvents using example: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android#hifunction-example you will need to use the `chart.getEvents().setLoad()`. Before you will need to initialize: `HIChart chart = new HIChart()` and add it to the option: `options.setChart(chart)`

Comment: Got the method and is executed. But it is executed before the graph is viewed on screen. I want  it to be done after all the points are drawn